# "error": "Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '_id')" when creating user

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, mongoose

I am trying to add some authentication to a web app and I am using a function for signing up with mongoose, the function for signing up is here:

```js
userSchema.statics.signup = async function(username, email, password){
    
    //validation
    if(!email || !password || !username){
        throw Error('All fields required');
    }
    if(!validator.isEmail(email)){
        throw Error('Email is Not Valid');
    }
    if(!validator.isStrongPassword(password)){
        throw Error('Password not strong enough');
    }

    const userExists = await this.findOne({username});
    const emailExists = await this.findOne({email});


    if(userExists){
        throw Error('Username in use')
    }

    if(emailExists){
        throw Error('Email in use')
    }

    const salt = await bcrypt.genSalt(10)
    const hash = await bcrypt.hash(password, salt);

    const user = await this.create({username, email, password: hash})

}
```

and then this function is called in the function sent to the post request here:

```js
const signupUser = async (req, res) => {
    const {username, email, password} = req.body;

    try{
        const user = await User.signup(username, email, password);

        //create token
        const token = createToken(user._id);

        res.status(200).json({username,email,token})
    }catch(error){
        res.status(400).json({error: error.message})
    }
}
```

The user is created just fine but the issue is with the response object, when I send the request in postman I get the response back of:

```json
{
    "error": "Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '_id')"
}
```

I have read other stackoverflow questions similar that received this error and attempted those solutions but none of those have worked. I have also logged user to console in the signupUser function and it is returning undefined, but in the signup function I also logged the value of user and it returns an object with all of the data I wanted user in the signupUser function to return

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that the `signup` function returns nothing (or *undefined*). This line is the problem: `const user = await User.signup(username, email, password);` You're calling the `signup` function, and assigning its return value -- remember, **nothing!** -- to a variable. Then, when you try to access a property of said variable, you're getting an error because you're reading the properties of nothing. By adding a return statement to `signup` with the user variable you declared in the function, you should be able to fix the issue.

Answer (score -1):

In my case I just have to adjest the place of router , So also check that , router should be defined below publivc __direct join

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).